# DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: ... ...no Connection Available error while setting up JPA with jboss

Tags: jpa, jboss, persistence.xml

I'm porting a glassfish jpa app to jboss and am running into this error:

**DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:**
  Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=Avengers.war#AvengersPU" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.hiberna
te.HibernateException: 'hibernate.dialect' must be set when no Connection available

The connection can be tested successfully using the jboss admin console and i can manually log into my db so i'm confused by this error message. Can someone advise as to what i have miss configured?

Here is my **mysql-ds.xml** file:

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/thor_ds</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/thor</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>apple</user-name>
    <password>apple</password>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>   
    <metadata>
       <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

and my **persistance.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="AvengersPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <!--<jta-data-source>jdbc/thor_ds</jta-data-source>-->
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/thor_ds</jta-data-source>
    <class>avenger.Grouptable</class>
    <class>avenger.MyUser</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**EDIT:** following JMelnik's instructions my config properties tags now has this:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **set your database dialect** in your persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DIALECT" />
</properties>
```

Replace DIALECT with a dialect from [a list of database dialects hibernate supports.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)

Comment: Thanks! I kept cranking along and am currently stuck with this scenario incase you are willing to take a peak. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300316/can-not-create-entitymanager-factory-bc-jta-tx-manager-requiered

Comment: @simgineer, you miss JTAtransaction manager, find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212075/the-chosen-transaction-strategy-requires-access-to-the-jta-transactionmanager-or